# use MySQL trigger for updating tables of a view

Tags: mysql, view

I have a view using "Union", so not updatable.
For practical reasons, it would be really nice to be able to send insert/update/delete queries on this view.
(everything is old and there are too many things and as always no time and money to redo everything)

Is it possible to use trigger for intercept update/insert/delete, change the table name of the original query to the target table, execute the query on the target table and not do it on the view?

Comment: Your description is too general.

Comment: ok, sorry.
i have 40 tables with the same scheme used by different system. I can't merge all in the same table but one of these system need, now, to use all these table. So i create a view based on a select * union all the tables.
It's ok for select queries.
But i can't update/insert/delete this view. So my idea is to use trigger for intercept queries and execute them on the right table. I can't change the system for to do that.

Comment: A trigger doesn't replace the original query. So even if you could add a trigger on the view, and it updated the intended target table, you'd still get an error when the original query tries to update the view after the trigger runs.

Comment: o_O Well... imagine that you have realized this. The query inserts a row - what table from these 40 ones this row must be inserted into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. The [CREATE VIEW documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) specifically says:

> You cannot associate a trigger with a TEMPORARY table or a view.

Comment: No luck for me...